# How to overcome t.test error in R as numeric already tried?

Tags: r, testing, statistics, mean

I have been performing a t.test on a set of dataframe which looks the following: 
[image]

```
crime_pc %>%
  filter(year==2016) %>%
  t.test(crime_pc$robbery_pc, alternative = "two.sided", mu = 110)
```

However, I ran into error:

```
Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In var(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: what is class( crime_pc$robbery_pc)

Comment: How to check it?

Comment: I was dividing in that var before

Comment: Like that, just run `class( crime_pc$robbery_pc)`. Or `str(crime)`.

Comment: So it is float then?

Comment: [1] "numeric" that is the output

Comment: If it returns `"numeric"`, then yes, it is float.

Comment: Do you have `NA` values in that vector? Run `summary(crime_pc)`. Or `sum(is.na(crime_pc$robbery_pc))`.

Comment: There are no NA values

Comment: what is class( crime_pc$year)

Comment: Just solved see below

Answer (score -2):

Main problem is absence of unlist function

```
 ttest <- crime_pc %>%
  select(robbery_pc) %>%
  unlist %>% #helps to remove dataframe and transform it into vector
  t.test(alternative="two.sided",mu=110)
ttest
```

Comment: SO aims to be a collection of answers to specific coding issues, demonstrating good coding practices and usefulness beyond that of the original question. Your answer doesn't tick either of these boxes; not only does your "answer" obfuscate the issue, it also presents a very poor coding implementation in itself. This has nothing to do with earning commenter badges. I suggest familiarising yourself with SO posting guidelines. This "answer" should be deleted.